# how long is a key being pressed in java

Tags: java, keyevent

well i'm making a program and it should do something after the key 'f' was pressed for 3 seconds, if it wasn't pressed for 3 seconds then it shouldn't do anything, i know how to know if a key is being pressed and released but i don't find any method to know the time of being pressed

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    // to know if a key is being pressed

}
private void formKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    // to know when a key is released

}
```

**Edit:** 
Nevermid about those answers, it didn't work. to make it work i had to do this:

```
private long keyPressedMillis;
private boolean alreadyPassed==false;
...
private void formKeyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
if(alreadyPassed==false)
keyPressedMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
alreadyPassed=true;
}
private void forKeyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
long keyPressLength = System.currentTimeMillis() - keyPressedMillis;
    alreadyPassed=false;
    System.out.println("Key Pressed "+keyPressLenght+" ms");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long whenTheKeyWasPressed;

private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    whenTheKeyWasPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

private void formKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if ((now - whenTheKeyWasPressed) >= 3000L) {
        ...
    }
}
```

That will only trigger the action when the key is released, though. If you want to trigger the action when the time reaches 3 seconds, then start a swing Timer in the keyPressed() method, and stop it from the keyReleased() method.

Comment: it didn't work , i wanted it to show a Message like "SS" after pressing 3 seconds the key but it didn't show anything

Comment: We're not extra-luci wizards. We thus can't explain why your code doesn't work without seeing your code. Edit your question and post your code.

Comment: i already got  it , it was giving a value to 'whenTheKeyWasPressed' everything , i mean like 10 ms before i released it that was the problem, i fixed it with a if so it only gives the value on the first ms i pressed the key

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of when the key was pressed and calculate how long when released.

```
long keyPressedMillis;

private void onKeyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    keyPressedMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

private void onKeyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
    long keyPressLength = System.currentTimeMillis() - keyPressedMillis;
    if (keyPressLength >= 3000) {
        //do whatever you need
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand what does System.currentTimeMillis() do , can you explain it ?

Comment: it didn't work, i did         System.out.println("SS"); and then pressed a key for 4  seconds but didn't print anything